# How to run PyCharm from Docker?

Tags: docker, pycharm

I was able to build a docker image from the path where my Dockerfile is saved that contains installation instructions for PyCharm. At building the image, I am able to view the list of images created. then i typed docker run ti -pycharm which is the name of the image i built in the terminal and I have my container running. Now I am stuck at how to load Pycharm from this container? Thanks

Comment: PyCharm is an IDE. While I think it's possible to run a GUI application from a container, it's not a typical use-case. Why do you want to run PyCharm from inside a docker container?

Comment: to be honest i am not sure myself, i was just asked to try this approach since I was not able to run a python script on my main machine due to the lack of certain packages and by running it from the container it is installed along with the libraries required to be able to run this script which worked. but since i am new to the docker concept, i lost the way to run pycharm from the container and when i attempted to run the application again, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I understand your problem now. You need to be able to run a python script which your host machine does not have the dependencies for.

---

As an aside, a common way to manage python dependencies is with [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). If you're unfamiliar with it and you want a simple way to manage python dependencies, you should read more about it since this might be the best solution.

---

Using Docker as a way to manage python dependencies can also work well, and is a relatively new practice that is probably becoming more common. In this case, *you do not want to run PyCharm from inside the Docker container*. Instead, you should develop in PyCharm on your host machine, and use the container simply to run your python script.

The best way to illustrate how this works is probably with an example. For simplicity, create a new folder, cd to it, and create a simple python script (`hello.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hello, world!")
```

Now, we can run the following Docker command:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 python hello.py
```

That command will mount the current directory into the container as /usr/src/myapp. When you do this with your project, that should be your project directory. The command sets the workdir in the container to /usr/src/myapp so we can use relative paths. Simply change `hello.py` at the end of the command to the relative path of the script you want to run.

Because your project folder is mounted into the container as a volume, you can edit the code in PyCharm on your host machine and run the script inside the container. This example used the default python 3 container, but it is simple to replace that image name in the above command with the name of the image you want to use, which can already have your required dependencies installed.

Comment: thank you very much. i will try this out as it seems to be a practice that will be good to be adopted in the long run.

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't allow running the debugger in PyCharm.  Outside the scope of the OP, but still...

Comment: PyCharm can use Docker as an interpreter and can debug it. You'd need to configure this in the IDE itself. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html But yeah, a bit outside the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues that exist when running an IDE either inside or outside of docker.

When running PyCharm on the host with the python interpreter inside of a docker, sharing the codebase can be handled by

1. PyCharm's remote interpreter functionality

   - Over SSH: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html
   - Over Docker TCP port: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html
   - The code resides on the host, which is necessary for PyCharm to provide static analysis. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-inspection.html
   - Whenever you want to run the code, it needs to synced with the remote system. I'm not sure how the synchronization behaves, so I don't know if the syncing is two way, or if PyCharm on the host always overwrites the remote system (docker container) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-synchronization-with-a-remote-host.html
2. Mounting a host directory inside the docker container:

   - Docker Desktop on Windows has a lot of limitations when mounting a Windows directory inside the docker container.

     - The linux container cannot change the permissions of files inside the Windows directory. The files always appear to have the permissions 755 (rwxr-xr-x). If you try to mount your openssh configs or keys inside the linux container, ssh on linux will refuse to use those files because they are insecure.
       https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#permissions-errors-on-data-directories-for-shared-volumes
     - The linux container will not get filesystem events (inotify) letting it know that files have changed on the file mounted from Windows. If you use `./manage.py runserver` to run Django in development, it would need to poll all the files in the codebase to see if there are any changes. I have not tested Django's polling. If it does not work sufficiently quickly, you may have to restart Django so that it reflects your changes. 
       https://william-yeh.net/post/2019/06/inotify-in-containers/
     - This works much better when the host is a Mac, because the osxfs mounted volumes work better with linux containers. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/

       3. Mounting a directory in the linux container on Windows.
     - SSHFS with WinFSP allows Windows to mount the files over ssh. This requires an ssh server to be installed in the linux container. An NFS or Samba server on the linux container could also be used for file sharing but with similar problems.
     - PyCharm on Windows does not support polling for file changes. If you mount the codebase over ssh, NFS, or SMB, PyCharm will not know if you have added a new file. This is especially an issue if you switch to a different branch for your codebase.

Currently, I'm experimenting with running PyCharm inside the linux container.

- With Docker Desktop for Windows, you cannot use the JetBrains Toolbox to install PyCharm, because it is installed with an AppImage that requires support for the fuse kernel driver. It appears that docker is making advancements in this area, but my version of Windows 10 is not part of the Insider Preview, so I haven't tested these new features.
  https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/12/docker-desktop-windows-fuse/
- You can just install the pycharm tarball and run that. You will definitely need to increase the memory and swap in the Resources settings for Docker Desktop.
- So that the linux container can display a gui application, Windows needs to run an xserver such as VcXsrv. After you start that, you can set the env var `DISPLAY=localhost:0`. By specifying `localhost` and not just `DISPLAY=:0`, any gui app that you run will know that it needs to connect to VcXsrv over TCP instead of looking for a unix socket that does not exist.
- By running PyCharm inside of the linux container, I also don't have to think about crlf conversion settings in Git. https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

Comment: A few years later for a Vite project, I found running Pycharm in Win11/WSL2 to be the least frustrating in terms of HMR support. WSL seems to support Toolbox and GUI well enough. The Pycharm WSL remote backend + Pycharm Windows client had some inconsistent interface bugs.